# Styling the clickedit output

Tags: javascript, php, css

I am using `clickedit` plugins that edit the label and output the edited text. What I am aiming to do is format the output after clicking and editing the label.

HTML:

```
<p class="text-center">
    <font size="5" color="#38283C">
        <b><i><span id="mto-num-detail">KTR-2-KTR2-PR-C-00002</span></i></b>
    </font>
</p>
<input class="form-control clickedit" type="text"/>
```

JavaScript:

```
// EDIT ON CLICK
var defaultText = 'Click To Input Custom PO Number';

function endEdit(e) {
    var input = $(e.target),
        p = input && input.prev();

    p.text(input.val() === '' ? defaultText : input.val());
    input.hide();
    p.show();
}

$('.clickedit').hide()
.focusout(endEdit)
.keyup(function (e) {
    if ((e.which && e.which == 13) || (e.keyCode && e.keyCode == 13)) {
        endEdit(e);
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
})

.prev().click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).next().show().focus();
});
```

My question is how do I generate the same format as the initial text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a class in css like

```
.color-text{ color : #F00;}
```

And in click event add this class.

```
$('selector').addClass('color-text');
```